# Find area integral

Tags: probability, integration, definite-integrals, area

Given the line $y = 2x$, I need to find the area of the region below it.

> Original question:
>
> - Two numbers $x$ and $y$  chosen randomly from interval $\left[0,1\right]$, find the probability that $2x > y$.
> - In order to prove that, I need to find the area of the region under the line
>     $y = 2x$. The answer is $3/4$. How can I get this result ?.

Comment: The support of $(X, Y)$ is a unit square.  As you said $2x = y$ is a straight line. And this line intersect with the square and form a triangle. And thus...

Comment: Base by height divided by 2?

Comment: The answer is 3/4. How?

Answer (score 0):

First, imagine your input space as being in the first quadrant, where there's a unit square with vertices $(0,0), (1,0), (1,1), (0,1)$. Draw this out. Now draw the line $y=2x$. If you pick any point $(x,y)$ where $x \in [0,1], y \in [0,1]$, it will fall somewhere in this unit square. You need to figure out what part in this square satisfies $y < 2x$. I find it easier to work with the probability that $y \geq 2x$ and then you can easily find the other probability. So if we're trying to find the probability that $y \geq 2x$, you shade the upper part of the triangle bounded by the line $y = 2x$ and the top of the unit square ($y = 1$). Color this triangle in.

You can now compute where the line $y=2x$ intersects the line $y=1$. From here, you now have the width and height of this colored-in triangle. Compute the area of that, and divide by the area of the unit square. This gives you the probability, which comes out to be $.25$. This is the probability, remember, that $y \geq 2x$. To find the complement of this probability, that $y < 2x$, you just do $1 - .25 = .75$.

Comment: @Singh, you're welcome. Please mark this as accepted if you found this to sufficiently answer your question by clicking the checkmark next to the up and down arrows, and it's good to do this for your other questions too.

Comment: Hey, I tried to do it then. But I don't have 15 points yet, so my vote doesn't count. And I wasn't even allowed to comment then, so I couldn't clarify. But thanks a lot and happy new year.

Answer (score 0):

In fact you need to use not only the fact that $x\in [0,1]$ but also the fact that $y\in [0,1]$.

Calculate the total area of the region $x,y\in [0,1]$: it is $1\times 1=1$. Now we have to calculate the total area below the graph of $y=2x$ in the region $x,y\in [0,1]$. This is the tricky part since it is in fact not a triangle but a trapezoid. To see this, calculate $y(x=1)=2\times1=2$, which is bigger than $1$, the maximum of $y$ in our region. We therefore use height $1$ for our trapezoid. One base length is just the interval $x\in [0,1]$ whose length is $1$. The other base is the interval between the boudary of our region $(1,1)$ and the intersection of the lines $y=1, y=2x$. That intersection is $(\frac12,1)$, and therefore the length of this base is $1-\frac12=\frac12$. The area of the trapezoid is therefore $A=\frac12((1+\frac12)\times1)=\frac34$, and the probability is the area of the trapezoid divided by the area of the region $P=\frac{\frac34}{1}=\frac34$, as requested.